# Spring Custom Access Denied Handler not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, access-denied

I developed a Microservice Architecture with Spring. Therefor I have implemented one auth service and one userinterface service.
The Session is shared with redis. So The worklow is that you login on the auth-login page and after success you get redirected to the ui resource.
So far so good. I also implemented authorization by user role the secure my resources on the controller level.

**What I want:**
Even when login was successful it should not be possible change the url and enter a restricted area. So when a client tries to do this an Access-denied Exception gets thrown atm.
In that case I want to invalidate the session and redirect to the login page of the auth service.

**What I did:**
I followed [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-access-denied-page) tutorial by baeldung to implement a custom accessdeniedhandler.

**Code:**

> CustomAccessDeniedHandler.java

```
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {

      response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8000/login");
        
    }
}
```

> SpringSecurity.java

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
     @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
            
        }
     
     @Bean
     public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler(){
         return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
     }
     
}
```

**What happens:**
I've set a breakpoint in my handler but it is not thrown and the general access-denied message gets thrown. Is there something I forgot to register in the implementation?

Thank you guys

Comment: You said you have multiple services. Which one is this `SpringSecurityConfiguration` in? Also, are you certain (e.g., with a breakpoint in the `configure` method) that the configuration class is being applied?

Comment: I have configured security in both services. The code in the description is in the ui service. I just set my breakpoint in both methods. The init is executed but the handler not gets called

Comment: @medTech is it possible that missing `@EnableWebSecurity` in `SpringSecurityConfiguration` causes the problem? By investigating resources' source code [Spring Security – Customize the 403 Forbidden/Access Denied Page](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-mvc-login/src/main/java/com/baeldung) your example seems to be fine

Comment: Thank's for your feedback. I've added this annotation at my main class where I also set @Springapplication. Is it necessary to set this annotation multiple times in the code or at specific classes. I can't test it atm but I will provide feedback tomorrow.

Comment: @FishingIsLife did u solve the problem?

Comment: I ended up using keycloak with oauth 2.0 / openid Connect. IT works like charm and The logic is separated and encapsulated. I recommend to give it a try